# How stop start tomcat service in ubuntu using ant?

Tags: ant, tomcat6, ubuntu-12.04

I have jenkins on jetty on test server (ubuntu 12.04) and I need stop/start tomcat before deploy my war file.
I can start tomcat over ant with target:

> ```
> <target name="tomcat-start">
>     <java jar="${tomcat.home}/bin/bootstrap.jar" fork="true" >
>         <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${tomcat.home}"/>
>     </java> </target>
> ```

But if I check /etc/init.d/tomcat6 status i see  "* Tomcat servlet engine is not running."

How to stop start tomcat service in ubuntu using ant?

Answer (score 0):

here is the link startup & shutdown tomcat. This will be helpful.

http://fugoconsulting.wordpress.com/tag/startup-and-shutdown-of-tomcat-in-ubuntu/